# Communication from Tomcat to Apache Web Server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat

I have deployed my application in Apache Tomcat, and I am using Tomcat as a standalone web server. Now from my application, I am sending request to a plugin which is in Apache Web Server for getting some information. I want to configure security. What I want is that Tomcat should produce SSL certificate before sending the request, proving it's identity and so does Apache Web server should do to prove it's identity.Tomcat and Apache Web Server are not on the same machine. What I have got till now through google is how to configure Apache Web Server to contact to Tomcat i.e. using mod_jk or mod_proxy. I don't want that.

Possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but this is nothing to do with Tomcat configuration. Configure httpd for TLS, including making client certificates required, and then code your application using your preferred Java HTTP client to make an HTTPs connection to httpd with a certificate. The code is the same whether it runs in a stand-alone Java application or on Tomcat.